# require('wp-blog-header.php') does not work in a loop

Tags: wordpress, function, loops, external

I'm trying to use wp_insert_post from an external php file. This file works fine if there is no loop. It took me quite a long time but i cannot search for any similar information.

```
<?php

require('wp-blog-header.php');
$tmpstr = array(
          'ID' => 1,
          'post_title' => $title,
          'post_content' => $post content,
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'post_author' => '1',
          'post_type' => $type
       );
wp_insert_post($tmpstr);
?>`
```

However, when i put a loop,

```
<?php
for ($i=0;$i<10,$i++) {
require('wp-blog-header.php');
$tmpstr = array(
          'ID' => 1,
          'post_title' => $title[$i],
          'post_content' => $post content[$i],
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'post_author' => '1',
          'post_type' => $type
        );
   wp_insert_post($tmpstr);
}
?>
```

It insert only 1 time into mysql database, then it stops
I have tried changing the require('wp-blog-header.php'); to require('/path/to/wp-blog-header.php'); but it still does not solve my problem. If i comment out the wp_insert_post and require('wp-blog-header.php'); and add echo $post_content[$j];echo $post_title[$j]; all values are displayed correctly in my browser

Could anyone please help me to make it loop for 10 times, so that it can insert 10 entries?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Change `$i=0;$i<10,$i++` to `$i=0;$i<10;$i++`

Comment: If you need to put a require statement into a loop, it's maybe a very bad design problem...

Comment: Sorry, the comma is a typo in my question. The original code is still correct. It still does not loop for 10 times, stops after the first round

Comment: @H2CO3 Could you suggest a way to deal with this? I also feel it is not good to put the require in a loop, but don't know any other way

Comment: It depends on what you want to accomplish. At first glance, isn't it sufficient if you just put that outta loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are constantly requiring the file per loop. NEVER DO THAT. put the require outside the loop. If you put it in the loop, PHP will error out saying that the function is already defined.

```
<?php
require('wp-blog-header.php');
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
$tmpstr = array(
          'ID' => 1,
          'post_title' => $title[$i],
          'post_content' => $post content[$i],
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'post_author' => '1',
          'post_type' => $type
        );
   wp_insert_post($tmpstr);
}
```

Comment: okay, Thank you very much, i have resolve the problem with your same code, except that i have to comment out the 'ID' => 1 since it overwrites the previous entry :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i=0;$i<10,$i++) {
               ^
```

ERROR! Must be:

```
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
               ^
```

Comment: Yeah, that is my typo in this question, but the original code is still correct :-(